# Why do I need Int function

Tags: vba, range

A. How does the Int fuction help in this code?
B. Why is +1 added to Rnd when it works fine without +1

Tried removing +1

```
Function DrawOne(Range As Variant, Optional ReCalc As Variant = False)

    'Chooses one cell at Random from a Range and returns range contents
    'make Function volatile if Recalc is True
    Application.Volatile ReCalc

    'Determine a Random cell
    DrawOne = Range(Int(Range.Count) * Rnd + 1)

End Function
```

Comment: Not sure about placement of brackets but it is I guess to ensure a positive whole number is passed to Range to avoid erroring out.

Comment: It would appear this is a typo. This code looks almost like the [example for the documentation for `Rnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function#example) to get a random number between X and Y. If that is the case, it should have been `Int((Range.Count * Rnd) + 1)`, and would have returned a whole number between 1 and `Range.Count`.

Comment: ^^ that looks right!

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the `Int()` function is that `Range.Count * Rnd` can return a decimal value over 0.50.  When this happens the value will be rounded up, which will give you an upper bounds 1 high than intended.

[image]

Here is a simple test using a modified version of the OP's code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim n As Long
    Dim result As Double
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = Range("A1:A10")
    For n = 1 To 1000
        If Intersect(Target, DrawOne(Target)) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "DrawOne mising Int() function failure"
            End
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Function DrawOne(Range As Range) As Range
    Set DrawOne = Range(Range.Count * Rnd + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: The `Int` in the OP's code is called only on `Range.Count` which is an integer already. The `Rnd` call is outside of the `Int` call.

Comment: @GSerg   good point.  I didn't think to mention that his bracketing is off.